# SpringBoot dependencies

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot 2.1.3.RELEASE project, that uses this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.plats</groupId>
    <artifactId>plats-sec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>system</scope> 
    <systemPath>/Users/lopes/WS/plats/target/plats-sec-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Nevertheless I can't use any class of the dependency, since I have this compilation error:

> The import com.plats.backend.persistence.domain cannot be resolved

I also tried

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=plats-sec-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.plats -DartifactId=plats-sec -Dversion=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

and using

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.plats</groupId>
        <artifactId>plats-sec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

with the same result

Comment: try this ..Right click `Project -> Maven -> Update project ` should work.

Comment: I;ve done it with the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your IDE. in general maven dependencies with `<scope>system</scope>` should be avoided, as this leads to unstable builds and releases (see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies)

If you - as it seems to be in you setup - want to access a locally build dependency within another project, then you can

1. point both projects to the same local maven repository
2. build the dependency with `mvn install`
3. and ensure that you spring boot project does a refresh of the dependencies (like `mvn clean install -U` on console)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried maven build and then maven update through your command prompt? Try them once so that you can check if they have any problems in the files.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment as it doesn't answer the question.